# HDFS error + Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs://l27.0.0.1:9000

Tags: hadoop, flume, webhdfs, bigdata

I run flume on hadoop with command

```
flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/flume-twitter.conf -n TwitterAgent
```

and Now i am not able to save the twitter data. It shows error. 
I posted the error below. Can you have any idea ??

```
    2016-01-29 15:48:56,979 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [DEBUG - com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource$1.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:108)] ArtistLR: RT Ar
    tsUK1 An unlikely duo: Homeland's Nina Hoss plots with art joker Christian Janko

wski #Arts https://t.co/hJyClDCgk0
    2016-01-29 15:48:57,136 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:234)] Creatin
    g hdfs://l27.0.0.1:9000/tweets/movies/2016/01/29/15//FlumeData.1454062721600.tmp
    2016-01-29 15:48:57,139 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:455)] HD
    FS IO error
    java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs://l27.0.0.1:9000/tweets/movies/2016/01/29/15/FlumeData.1454062721600.tmp
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
            at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:243)
            at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:235)
            at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:679)
            at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
            at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:676)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    2016-01-29 15:48:57,334 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.stop(LifecycleSupervisor.java:79)] Stopping lifecycle s
    upervisor 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the URL: `l27.0.0.1` has a small L instead of the digit 1. A typo in the configuration?

Comment: It *should* be 1. I agree. But the stack trace you pasted definitely has the small L.